# Alert not being called in success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am using ajaxfileupload.js and the form is submitting and it goes in to the error handler function but it data.msg seems to be undefined?

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajaxFileUpload({
      url           : './upload_file/',
      secureuri     : false,
      type          : 'post',
      fileElementId : 'userfile',
      dataType      : 'json',
      data          : {
            'title'       : $('#title').val(),
            'publication' : $('#publication').val(),
            'description' : $('#description').val()
      },
      success : function(data, status){
         alert('test');
         if(data.status != 'error'){
            $('#files').html('<p>Reloading files...</p>');
            refresh_files();
         },
         error : function(data, status){
            $('#alerts').html(data.msg);
         }                      
      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

Controller:

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
```

Comment: Is the HTTP code of the response a 200? If not, it'll be sent to the `error` handler (which you don't have) not the `success` handler.

Comment: indeed, add an `error` handler and confirm it's working as expected. A response doesn't mean it was a successful response. (I'm not fluent in ajaxFileUpload, but maybe you have a JSON parsing error which is causing the plugin to trip up and error out).

Comment: As mentioned, you should add a `complete` and `error` handler to see what is happening exactly. If there is an error it will not be processed by the `success` handler.

Comment: Ok when I do this it alerts but the msg is undefined, in my controller I have this: echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));

Answer (score 0):

implement an 'error' handler in your ajax call, otherwise you will never know if your service ran successfully